# How to redirect HTML page on successful login using PhoneGap iOS?

Tags: php, html, ios, cordova

I have designed a form using HTML and CSS and am using phpMyAdmin as backend where I can save user data and use it for login purposes. I have successfully connected phpMyAdmin, saving data successfully and verifying it in login page.

Now my problem is if the login is successful it has to load HTML page `empaccess.html`. I don't know to how to do it in PHP.

Here is my PHP code (empcheck.php):

```
<?php   
$a=$_POST['text3'];
$b=$_POST['text4'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","","crm");
mysql_select_db("crm") or die("Error in Connection");
if (empty($_POST['text3']) && empty($_POST['text4']))
{
  echo "<h1><center>PLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD</center></h1>";
  exit();
}
$query="SELECT * from emmreg WHERE username='$a'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("");
    $uname=$row['username'];
    $pwd=$row['password'];
     if($a==$uname && $b==$pwd)
     {

       echo "Success";
        //header('location:index.html');
      }

else
 {
   echo "INCORRECT PASSWORD";

 }
}mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP:**

```
header('Location: http://example.com/page.php');
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="seconds; url=URL">
```

it'll redirect to another page on load.

Answer (score 1):

use `header()`, and dont try to echo or try to get any output before [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
if($result)
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("");
    $uname=$row['username'];
    $pwd=$row['password'];
    if($a==$uname && $b==$pwd)
     {
      header('location:empaccess.html');
     }
     else
     {
     header('location:index.html');;

     }
}
```

Comment: I tried But it still shows error. Note: am trying in IOS simulator.